# Show tool tip relative with parent element using CSS

Tags: css, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I need help to show the tool tip relatively with parent element. Refer screen 1 it's show the description is perfect [screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EE7TG.png). But screen 2 [Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUs4W.jpg) when i scroll the section description show the same place but i need relative

```
<div class="item" data-key="15" data-value="244937">
    <input class="option" id="treemultiselect-0-15" type="checkbox">
    <span class="description">
        <label class="" for="treemultiselect-0-15">Ashram</label>
    </span>
    <div class="temp-description-popup" style="position: absolute;">
        No. &amp; Listing of <b>Ashrams</b><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please share a code snippet for this.

Comment: how to add tool tips? in title attribute or other div.

Comment: Other div (<div class="temp-description-popup" style="position: absolute;">No. &amp; Listing of <b>Ashrams</b><br> </div>)

Comment: to which element you gave the `position: relative`?

Comment: For description div i gave its not working perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this, right?

It's better you create a snippet & re-create your issue, so everyone can catch the idea & help you out.

The problem is that you set the element `position: absolute`, so it just keep the position based on its `relative` parent. Scrolling won't move it.

This example will help you better in understanding how position works https://codepen.io/AlHakem/pen/YayxBo

```css
.scroller {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
}

.temp-description-popup {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0px;
}

.item:hover>.temp-description-popup {
  visibility: visible;
  height: auto;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  z-indeX: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller">
  <div class="item" data-key="15" data-value="244937">
    <input class="option" id="treemultiselect-0-15" type="checkbox">
    <span class="description">
        <label class="" for="treemultiselect-0-15">Ashram</label>
    </span>
    <div class="temp-description-popup">
      No. &amp; Listing of <b>Ashrams</b><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-key="15" data-value="244937">
    <input class="option" id="treemultiselect-0-15" type="checkbox">
    <span class="description">
        <label class="" for="treemultiselect-0-15">Ashram</label>
    </span>
    <div class="temp-description-popup">
      No. &amp; Listing of <b>Ashrams</b><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-key="15" data-value="244937">
    <input class="option" id="treemultiselect-0-15" type="checkbox">
    <span class="description">
        <label class="" for="treemultiselect-0-15">Ashram</label>
    </span>
    <div class="temp-description-popup">
      No. &amp; Listing of <b>Ashrams</b><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-key="15" data-value="244937">
    <input class="option" id="treemultiselect-0-15" type="checkbox">
    <span class="description">
        <label class="" for="treemultiselect-0-15">Ashram</label>
    </span>
    <div class="temp-description-popup">
      No. &amp; Listing of <b>Ashrams</b><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-key="15" data-value="244937">
    <input class="option" id="treemultiselect-0-15" type="checkbox">
    <span class="description">
        <label class="" for="treemultiselect-0-15">Ashram</label>
    </span>
    <div class="temp-description-popup">
      No. &amp; Listing of <b>Ashrams</b><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-key="15" data-value="244937">
    <input class="option" id="treemultiselect-0-15" type="checkbox">
    <span class="description">
        <label class="" for="treemultiselect-0-15">Ashram</label>
    </span>
    <div class="temp-description-popup">
      No. &amp; Listing of <b>Ashrams</b><br>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for  your answer. exactly i'm look like this but small change. In description i want look title attribute in html.

Comment: I saw you answered above in the comment that in the `div` not in `title`? 
I'm not quite sure what you want though.

Comment: Please refer this link
https://codepen.io/naveensaravanan/pen/OwyPWy, scroll down and check the last element

Comment: I adjusted the code, is it what you're looking for?